# SQL Column and value to key & value

Tags: sql-server

I want to turn the record from an SQL query that looks like this...

```
FirstName   Amount  PostalCode      LastName    AccountNumber
John        2.4     ZH1E4A          Fork        857685
```

to a key value pair that looks like this...

```
Key              Value

FirstName        John  
Amount           2.4
PostalCode       ZH1E4A    
LastName         Fork        
AccountNumber    857685
```

And I want to do it all within SQL.  I have looked at the pivot example but I am not sure that it will work for this.  I know I could use temp tables, union but I am hoping for a more elegant solution.  Anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t table(FirstName varchar(10),   Amount money,  PostalCode varchar(10),      
                 LastName varchar(10),   AccountNumber int)
INSERT @t values('John', 2.4, 'ZH1E4A', 'Fork', 857685)

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    [FirstName], 
    cast([Amount] as varchar(10)) [Amount], 
    [PostalCode], 
    [LastName], 
    cast([AccountNumber] as varchar(10)) [AccountNumber]
  FROM @t
)
SELECT [Key],Value
FROM CTE  
UNPIVOT      
(Value FOR [Key] IN           
([FirstName], [Amount], [PostalCode], [LastName], [AccountNumber]) ) AS unpvt
```

Result:

```
Key          Value
FirstName    John
Amount       2.40
PostalCode   ZH1E4A
LastName     Fork
AccountNumber 857685
```